# gitlab runner keeps having `backoff restaring failed container`

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I installed a gitlab runner with the steps provided where you register them, and chose the kubernetes executor.

But the runner has issues.
When describing the pod `kubectl describe  pod gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner-6b7bf4d766-9t4k6 -n gitlab-runner` I get:

```
  Type     Reason     Age                      From     Message
  ----     ------     ----                     ----     -------
  Normal   Created    23m (x3820 over 21d)     kubelet  Created container gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner
  Warning  Unhealthy  13m (x52289 over 21d)    kubelet  Readiness probe failed:
  Warning  BackOff    3m34s (x91334 over 21d)  kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container
```

The container was restarted 90000 times over 3 Weeks, which averages to 3 times per minute.
I don't really know what to do since the error message is just empty.
What could I do to debug the error?

Answer (score 1):

You should first check what he readiness probe is doing. Can you add the yaml manifest of the pod to your question?